# Probability of small solutions to an uniform random linear diophantine equation?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, discrepancy-theory, probabilistic-number-theory

Take the set $$T(c_1,\dots,c_t)=\{(x_1,\dots,x_t)\in\mathbb Z^t\backslash\{(0,\dots,0)\}:\sum_{i=1}^tc_ix_i\equiv0\bmod q\}$$ where $c_1,\dots,c_t\in(-q/2,q/2)\cap\mathbb Z$.

> What is probability over all $c_1,\dots,c_t\in(-q/2,q/2)\cap\mathbb Z$ that there is an $(x_1,\dots,x_t)\in T$ such that $\prod_{i=1}^t(|x_i|+1)<q^{\zeta}$ where $\zeta\in(0,1)$?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Yeap made mistake $n=t$.